# How to setup Marlin to use a moving bed (up-down)?

Tags: marlin, z-axis

I am building a 3D printer from scratch, the bed will only move on Z and the head will stay at the top of the printer and move X and Y.

How do I modify the Marlin firmware to have the bed lower as it prints instead of lift like most printers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control in Marlin what the direction of the stepper motor is, e.g. my Hypercube CoreXY printer (which has a similar setup like you described) has the following set (in the Marlin [`Configuration.h`](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/Configuration.h) file) to ensure the platform raises when it has to decrease height:

```
// Invert the stepper direction. Change (or reverse the motor connector) 
// if an axis goes the wrong way.
#define INVERT_Z_DIR true
```

Furthermore, it matters where the Z endstop is located, e.g. using a bed probe sensor or a min Z endstop, you need to home towards a decreasing height (in the direction of your probe/endstop):

```
// Direction of endstops when homing; 1=MAX, -1=MIN
#define Z_HOME_DIR -1
```

Don't forget to set a max Z height that falls within the printer volume, e.g.:

```
#define Z_MAX_POS 345
```

If the bed is heavy, you should also prevent the steppers to lose power when not being used, so at least set Z to `false`:

```
// Disables axis stepper immediately when it's not being used.
// WARNING: When motors turn off there is a chance of losing position accuracy!
#define DISABLE_Z false
```

Comment: This is very helpful, when I get things build this will really help me get my firmware set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To understand normal commands from a basic printer slicer, all movement commands in g-code are written to be away from the base layer as positive. Note that *technically* a "lower the bed" printer does violate Orthonormal coordinates unless you either swap X and Y while retaining 0 in the front-left corner or put 0 in the front-right corner, going left for +X (e.g. inverting that motor axis too) and back for -Y.

## Hardware

To *invert* the movement direction of an axis without rewriting the firmware there are two main ways, from mos invasive to easiest:

- Mount the actuator "upside-down" as that flips the rotational normal vector.
- use a left-hand-threaded rod and nut. This does not flip rotation but how rotation affects the bed.
- alter the stepper cables by "crossing" one of the phases leads. The motor rotates reversed to its commands now.

[image]

## Firmware

In Marlin, you can also just flip the direction of the motor via `configuration.h` by altering the line from `false` to `true`:

```
#define INVERT_Z_DIR true
```